# How to get local copy of repo as deployed on Heroku?

Tags: git, github, heroku, twilio

I ran the one-click Heroku deployment of the Twilio contact center at [this Github repo](https://github.com/nash-md/twilio-contact-center), and I'm trying to clone a local repo so I can make some modifications and re-deploy it to Heroku with those changes. But when I tried to create a local repo with:

```
heroku git:clone -a [my Heroku app name]
```

it created an empty repository on my local machine. I know that I can just clone it from Github, but I was thinking that maybe there were some configuration changes made in the process of Heroku deployment that should be reflected in my local version; how can I clone the Heroku version?  Or is there a way to confirm that the Github version is the same as what's deployed on Heroku?

I posted this on /r/twilio [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/twilio/comments/7m3933/how_to_get_local_copy_of_contact_center_repo_as/).